# Django REST Framework received JPEG file as a String to ImageField

Tags: python, django, flutter, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I have a model in Django like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.

class UserDetails(models.Model):

    def getFileName(self, filename):
        return 'profile_pics/'+str(self.user.id)+'/'+filename

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=getFileName, blank = True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default='UK')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='NA')
    birthday = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):

        try:
            return self.user.username
        except:
            return 'Deleted User - '+str(self.phone)
```

Then, I created a **REST API** that accepts **Multipart** requests to create a new user as well as save the `user_details` for the user. I am making the *multipart POST request* from my app in Flutter with the Image for the profile picture. The image is coming in the body of the request as a String instead of coming in as a file, where I could have read it with `request.FILES['profile_picture']`. The body of the request that I am getting by doing a `print(request.data)` is as follows:

```
Data: <QueryDict: {
'username': ['jonsnow'], 
'first_name': ['Jon'], 
'last_name': ['Snow'], 
'email': ['jonsnow@got.com'], 
'password': ['jonsnow'], 
'country': ['UK'], 
'gender': ['Male'], 
'birthday': ['2020-4-28'], 
'phone': ['5198189849'], 
'profile_picture': ['����\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00��\x00�\x00\t\x06\x07\x08\x07\x06\t\x08\x07\x08\n\n\t\x0b\r\x16\x0f\r\x0c\x0c\r\x1b\x14\x15\x10\x16 \x1d"" \x1d\x1f\x1f$(4,$&1\'\x1f\x1f-=-157:::#+?D?8C49:7\x01\n\n\n\r\x0c\r\x1a\x0f\x0f\x1a7%\x1f%77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777��\x00\x11\x08\x019\x01�\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01��\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x02\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x04\x02\x05\x06\x01\x07\x00\x08��\x00Q\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x02\x03\x05\x04\x06\x06\x07\x07\x03\x03\x01\t\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x12!\x051A\x06\x13"Qa2q��\x14B����\x07#3Rr�\x154Sbs��\x16$C����5��%c�DtEFd����\x17��\x00\x1a\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06��\x00(\x11\x01\x01\x00\x02\x01\x04\x02\x02\x02\x02\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x11\x03\x12!1A\x04\x13\x14Q\x05"aqBR�\x15��\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00�Cl�0ɵX��¸�iB�k; ...\uebe8?��']
}>
```

And `print(request.FILES)` is coming as: `Files: <MultiValueDict: {}>`

So, I made the Multipart REST API to handle this request like:

```
class SignUp(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser,]
    authentication_classes = [CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        data = request.data

        print('\n\nFiles: '+str(request.FILES)+'\n\n');
        print('\n\nData: '+str(data)+'\n\n');
        print('\n\nData: '+str(request.META)+'\n\n');

        ## Creating a basic user
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=data['username'], first_name = data['first_name'], last_name = data['last_name'], email = data['email'], password = data['password'])
        user.save()

        user_details = UserDetails()
        user_details.user = user

        rec_img_str = data['profile_picture']
        rec_img_bytes = rec_img_str.encode('utf-8')
        rec_img_writer = BytesIO(rec_img_bytes)
        uploaded_img = InMemoryUploadedFile(rec_img_writer, None, 'sample.jpg', 'image/jpeg', None, 'utf-8')

        user_details.profile_picture = uploaded_img
        user_details.country = data['country']
        user_details.gender = data['gender']
        user_details.birthday = datetime.strptime(data['birthday'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        user_details.phone = data['phone']
        user_details.verified = False
        user_details.save()

        return Response({'Message': 'Profile Created Successfully'})
```

Here, I read the `JPG` image that comes as a string in the field `profile_picture`, converted it to Byte form, put it into `BytesIO()`, and then stored it in `user_details.profile_picture` as an `InMemoryUploadedFile`. It saves as `sample.jpg` in my `MEDIA` directory, but when I try to open it, it comes as a blank image.

So, how do I save the `JPEG` image that is coming in as a string to a `ImageField` in Django?

***Here's my Flutter code, if it is needed for reference:***

```
void submit() async {
    MultipartRequest request = MultipartRequest("POST",
        Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/services/authentication/signup/"));

    request.fields['username'] = this.username.text;
    request.fields['first_name'] = this.first_name.text;
    request.fields['last_name'] = this.last_name.text;
    request.fields['email'] = this.email.text;
    request.fields['password'] = this.password.text;

    request.fields['country'] = "UK";
    request.fields['gender'] = this.gender;
    String birthdayStr = "${birthday.year}-${birthday.month}-${birthday.day}";
    request.fields['birthday'] = birthdayStr;
    request.fields['phone'] = this.phone_no.text;

    if (this.profilePicture != null) {
      print('Profile picture available');
      print(this.profilePicture.path);
      request.files.add(
        await MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'profile_picture',
          await this.profilePicture.readAsBytes(), //this.profilePicture is a File
          contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg'),
        ),
      );
    }

    StreamedResponse resp = await request.send();

    if (resp.statusCode < 200 || resp.statusCode >= 400) {
      print('There was an error in making the SignUp Request');
      print('Status code: ${resp.statusCode}');
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `profile_picture` contains valid data - compare it with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures `^F JFIF` (so it should start with: FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 in hex)

Comment: yes, first 12 bytes should be  FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01

Comment: @pskink I did `rec_bytes = profile_picture[0].encode('utf-8')` to get the bytes and then I did a `print(rec_bytes[:13])` and here's what I got: `b'\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x00`

Comment: what are the first 12 bytes in your file `sample.jpg`? what does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump show?

Comment: @pskink how do I check the bytes in the file? should I open the file in a text editor or something?

Comment: Here's what I got on the first line after doing that: `00000000  ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf  bd ef bf bd 00 10 4a 46  |..............JF|`

Comment: I tried a lot of things, including saving it as a file directly, but nothing worked. I think I'm doing it wrong on the flutter side that the image is not going into `FILES` (`request.FILES` in django) part of the request, but is going to the `body` (`request.data`) part of the request. I saw some videos where they used `mime` in flutter to specify the media type and they also specified the file name before posting the request. I've got to try it with that

Comment: @pskink it woked. The error was on the Flutter side. I added `final mimeTypeData =
        lookupMimeType(this.profilePicture.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8])
            .split('/');` and then adding flies to the multipart request like `request.files.add(
        await MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'profile_picture',
          this.profilePicture.path,
          contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]),
          filename: 'blah.jpg',
        ),
      );` and it worked